# MVC Editor Template path issue with Attribute Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC app with Areas and in one area I'm using a editor template called Address which is in the "Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/" folder.

The controller action which returns the view with the editor template is "EditUser(long userId)" in the User controller (which is in the Admin Area)

I have the editor template in the view as:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address, "../Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Address")
```

This also works without explicitly defining the path.

Accessing this page via "..Admin/User/EditUser?userId=1" works fine. However when I use attribute routing on EditUser as:

```
[Route("admin/user/{userId}/edit")]
```

The editor template resorts to using a default view. (basically shows a editor for everything in the model)

My question is how can I point to the editor template with the attribute routing mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

You can attribute the property in the ViewModel for which you want to use a special editor using `[UIHint]` to specify the name of the editor template.

```
public class ViewModel {
    [UIHint("Address")]
    public string Address {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Isn't the problem here related to the Razor engine not being able to find the path to the Address editor template?

Comment: Looks like it :( UIHint will search for templates in the normal fashion, i.e. Area\Views\{Controller}\, then Area\Views\Shared\, then Views\...

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved it by luck.

Basically I added a [RouteArea("Admin")] tag on top of my controller, added the route attribute to the action as normal and removed the explicit path from the Html.EditorFor and left MVC to decide where to look for the template.

Works like a charm.